# Im really confused as to why Im getting an error here

Tags: python, tkinter

I just dont understand why this wont run

```
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sign-up")

# Create the username and password labels and text fields
tk.Label(root, text="Username:").grid(row=0, column=0)
username_entry = tk.Entry(root)
username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Password:").grid(row=1, column=0)
password_entry = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Create the submit button
submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=write_to_file)
submit_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Create the write_to_file function
def write_to_file():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    # Open the file in write mode
    with open("users.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(f"{username},{password}\n")

    # Clear the text fields
    username_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    password_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

# Start the program
root.mainloop()
```

My IDE says there is an error on line 17 but im not sure what it is.
I have tried to run through debugging but I simply dont understand what is incorrect.

Comment: You need to move the `write_to_file` function to before you declare the `submit_button`.

Comment: @jprebys is right - this is just a scope issue. You're telling your button to use `write_to_file` as a command before defining it. In the future, it's best to include the full error traceback with your question so folks can better understand your issue and provide more accurate help.